# iOS - What is the easiest way to custom the segue ViewController depending on a TableView selected row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

**Problem** : Custom the segue view controller called when a row in a Table view is selected.

**Different solution that may not work** : 
1° Make a all custom TableView from a single view and associate a ViewController to each Cell.
2° Connect a NavigationController to the TableView segue and select the ViewController on the NavigationController when a row is selected.

Is it a more efficient and proper way to do it?

Comment: End recipe : 
1° In Main.storyboard, select the Prototype Cells, in Attribute inspector > Preset PrototypeCells to the number of ViewController.
2° For each cell, link the ViewController.
3° Use Alex below's answer to configure the segued (in Cell) ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the above, correct answer by Alexander I'd like to add a snippet of code explaining how to do what he said. It sounds like you want to customize the ViewController you are segueing to based on the cell selected.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Hawaii"]) {
        // Configure VC based on this case
    }
}
```

You can also use anything else you might associate with the cell, like the object it's associated with

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
self.list[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
You therefore assign one controller for multiple view.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW4

Answer (score 0):

Use prepareForSegue to init ViewController.

> Because segues can be triggered from multiple sources, you can use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the table view cell that the user tapped. You could use that information to set the data on the destination view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender: